# Two long layovers in Tokyo

Tags: international-travel, layovers, tokyo, vacations

I am heading to Vietnam and have two long layovers in Tokyo, Japan.  The first layover is August 22nd in Haneda at 5:00am.  I leave at 6:30pm the same day but out of Narita.  The second layover is September 4th in Narita at 7:55am.  I leave at midnight on September 5th out of Haneda. Was wondering what I should do/see? Where I can store my checked suitcase and carry-on suitcase?

Comment: "What should I do?" is off-topic; "where can I store my suitcase?" probably is not. In any case, you should not ask two questions in one.

Comment: 5am in Tokyo? Tsukiji Market, enjoy some sushi! Don't know where you'll store your suitcase though.